# I need to convert a bit[] into an [] of strings that represent each bit in the bit[]

Tags: c#, .net, bitarray

I'm working on an automated follow up system on highly antiquated techniques of registering the current status of a "Project" the GUI interaction in this system uses what are named "flags" that the user can "check" to designate the current status of a project. There are 11 possible boxes that can be checked and the system accepts multiple selections.

For example a user can select a check-box labeled "Confirmed" and or "Needs Follow Up" and or or "Is Scheduled" and or "Spoken with client" (There are 11 possible selections).

Here is the problem - whoever wrote this saved those selections to the database in a "bit sum" so the what you see is an int of the original bit[] for the check-box selections.

What I need to do is read the integer from the database and turn it back into a bit array of 11 values of 1 || 0 then from that bit array i need to determine which boxes of string value are checked in order to determine weather or not i need to perform an automated follow up.

So basically if "Confirmed" is checked i don't want to follow up
If "Needs-followup" is checked i need to follow up.

The problem here is that multiple selections can be present.

So after the int is turned into a bit[] we have for example

1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1 where each int represents a box checked.

i need to find a way to turn the above into an array of strings representing the box labels to determine which boxes are checked.

Comment: Be more specific about what exactly is stored in the database. Provide examples. Also provide examples of how you want to read these out, how you want to manipulate them, etc. I think in mapping this out you may be able to write some code, which you should have for this post: "Questions **asking for code** must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist"

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do this in C# would be to use a flags enumeration - this is exactly what your bit field is.

```
[Flags]
enum ProjectStatus
{
    Confirmed = 1,
    NeedsFollowUp = 2,
    SpokenWithClient = 4,
    ....
}
```

To test if a specific flag is set:

```
ProjectStatus status = (ProjectStatus)intFromDb;
if( ( status & ProjectStatus.Confirmed ) == ProjectStatus.Confirmed )
    // the Confirmed flag is set
```

There is also a `Enum.HasFlags` extension method that simplifies this if you are in .NET 4 or higher.

If you do not wish to do it this way, you can find out if the bit at position `x` is set by doing this:

```
bool isSet = ( intFromDb & ( 1 << x ) ) != 0;
```

And use that to build your string.

Edit: I'd also suggest you read up a bit on bitwise operators and what they do. This might be a good start: http://blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpLogicalBitwiseOps.aspx